# VBA Passing Variable to Recurring Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have two subs. The first sub (GetKeyWord) asks the user for keywords and stores them in a string array. The next sub (AlertFinder) takes in the particular string array and searches for it in a webpage. However, I want AlertFinder to run every x amount of minutes, but I don't want the user to be asked what keywords he/she is looking for everytime AlertFinder runs (only want to ask the user once at the beginning and have the string array stay constant after that). This is why I made GetKeyWord a separate sub, but now I am having trouble making AlertFinder run since it requres the string array from GetKeyWord to run.

Here is the code:

```
Sub GetKeyWords()


Dim numKey As Integer
Dim strTemp() As Variant

'Input Keywords

numKey = InputBox("How many keywords would you like to search for? (Integer)", "Integer Value Please")




For k = 1 To numKey
    ReDim Preserve strTemp(numKey - 1)
    strTemp(k - 1) = InputBox("Please enter keyword" & k)


Next


'Execute Alert Finder
Call AlertFinder(strTemp)
End Sub


Sub AlertFinder(strTemp() As Variant)


'Set Variables
Dim boolFound As Boolean
Dim txt As String
Dim strOutput As String
Dim tbl As HTMLTable, tables As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim tr As HTMLTableRow, r As Integer, i As Integer
Dim tRows As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim strCurrent As Variant

~bunch of code~

     Set ieDoc = ie.Document

    'Loop to refresh webpage every 25 minutes
    Do While True

        'Pause the script for x minutes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"))

        'AFter time is up, reload page and run Alert Finder Again
        ieDoc.Location.Reload (True)
        AlertFinder (strTemp)

        If Err <> 0 Then

            Wscript.Quit
        End If
    Loop

    Set ie = Nothing
  End Sub
```

The trouble arises where I try to call AlertFinder(strTemp) within AlertFinder itself, but strTemp comes from GetKeyWord which I want to remain constant and not have to run GetKeyWord every 5 minutes. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the "~bunch of code~", but you should probably extract the loop from `Sub AlertFinder` into its own `Sub` instead of using recursion.

Comment: thank you! do you mind elaborating?

Comment: The loop is keeping the script alive.  There is no reason to call `AlertFinder (strTemp)` again.  What is happening is that every 5 minutes you creating another copy of AlertFinder.  In 5 mins you have 2 copies of AlertFinder running, in 10 minutes there are 4 copies, in 15 minutes there are 16 copies....etc.

Comment: @ThomasInzina, i'm sorry but thats not true. The code isn't even running because I'm getting an error when calling AlertFinder(strTemp) in the loop. I ran the code the same way but with strTemp declared as an array in the AlertFinder sub, and the code works fine without multiplying itself.

Comment: The error is because you are calling a sub using parenthesis .  `AlertFinder strTemp` will fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who commented. What I ended up doing was declaring strTemp as a Public variable so it could be given a value in GetKeyword, and passed onto AlertFinder, while AlertFinder could also call itself (then removed all instances of strTemp() being declared in the GetKeyword sub). Worked just fine.

Public strTemp() as Variant

before all the subprocedures did the trick. Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem.